# In-app billing implementing: confirmed purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, billing, android-billing

This is part of the code to implement in-app billing. I have two doubts.

```
@Override
    public void onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState, String itemId,
           int quantity, long purchaseTime, String developerPayload) {
        if (Consts.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPurchaseStateChange() itemId: " + itemId + " " + purchaseState);
        }

        if (developerPayload == null) {
            logProductActivity(itemId, purchaseState.toString());
        } else {
            logProductActivity(itemId, purchaseState + "\n\t" + developerPayload);
        }

        if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            mOwnedItems.add(itemId);

            // At this point I have to put Premium changes
        }
    }
```

My questions:

1. At the point where I say "At this point I have to put Premium changes", how can I assure you that the application has been purchased?
2. I have understood that once the purchase is made, this can take a few hours to take effect. How do I ensure that my application will execute the code that's in point: "At this point I have to put Premium changes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reach this block

```
if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
    ...
}
```

Then you know the purchase is successful. To my experience, the delay after the purchase is made is never more than a couple of seconds. But the user could close the app before the confirmation.

That is why you should implement `restoreTransactions()` as well. Each time your activity opens it checks with the server whether the app has been bought.

```
/**
 * A {@link PurchaseObserver} is used to get callbacks when Android Market sends
 * messages to this application so that we can update the UI.
 */
private class MyPurchaseObserver extends PurchaseObserver {
    public DownloaderPurchaseObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(home, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingSupported(boolean supported) {
        ...
        yourBillingService.restoreTransactions();
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreTransactionsResponse(RestoreTransactions request,
            ResponseCode responseCode) {
        if (responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_OK) {
            // repeat your premium validation here
        } else {
            if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                Log.e(TAG, "RestoreTransactions error: " + responseCode);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: NathanZ, thanks for your speed response! I have a one more doubt. My problem: I start the related billing services when I call MyBuyActivity.java, but while the user not click in the button, the billing services never be start. Then, if I refunded he the price, the app will be Premium for always. How can I call the billing services from my main Activity? The same case will be if the purchase take a few hours to take effect (although rare to happen). Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: See this post about refunds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817507/android-in-app-billing-cancel-payment