# After an in-app purchase, can the extra features purchased be time-limited?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

We have an application for the PC and we're thinking of writing an Android version of it.  But I have a question about how Google Play and in-app purchases work.

On our PC version, the basic version of the app is free, and users upgrade to the paid version to get more features.  But rather than "purchase" the app, they effectively "subscribe" - in other words, their upgrade is valid for a specific period of time, during which the extra features are available.  They also get free updates and support during that time.

The mechanism for this is that they buy the upgrade and get a license key which they enter into the application.  Every time they open the application, it pings our server to check whether the key is still valid.  If it isn't, only the basic features of the application are available to them.  Obviously they have to be online when they open the application, otherwise they can't ping the server.

The question is how we transfer this model to Android.

We want to make the app available in Google Play, so it has to conform to their rules, which I understand means users can download a basic version for free, and any subsequent purchase has to be done via Google Play, which is fine with me in principle.  Rather than have a free app and a paid one, we'd prefer to have just one.

So my favoured option so far is to offer one app with the premium features locked until the user upgrades via an inapp purchase.  My questions are:

1 - can the in-app upgrade contain a time limit?
2 - if the user has upgraded, is it technically possible for us to force the app to regularly ping our server in order to keep the extra features activated?

We offer refunds on demand for the software, because it's complicated to use, so if we do refund someone, I'd like to be able to deactivate their key on our server.

Grateful for any thoughts you have!

Answer (score 0):

1) There are "[consumable good](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume)s" and [subscriptions](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html)

2) An android app can contact your server via e.g. http. But I'd prefer to do everything via google play, if possible.

3) Note that Google takes a percentage of the in-app purchase cost, so if you refund... will the Google also refund? See [Android In-App billing cancel payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817507/android-in-app-billing-cancel-payment)

Note also the limit of IIRC 20 goods per request in the API, the example code has a bug related to that limit.

Comment: Thanks, very useful to know about the "consumable goods" and "subscriptions".  But when you say you would prefer to do everything via Google Play, are you talking about the payment?  The reason for pinging the server was not to make payment but to know if the user had a valid license, and to be able to turn their license off if necessary.  Are you saying that can be done by Google Play?

Comment: You ask GPlay which goods are purchased. If it tells you that the user has purchased, say, application's ability to speak Klingon, you can just turn on that feature. As I understand, subscriptions (I did not use them) are different from goods only in that they expire monthly or annually.

Comment: When you say "YOU ask GPlay" and "YOU turn on that feature", I assume you mean the app, not me personally.  So if a customer needs a refund, do I refund him on GPlay and that disables whatever it was he paid for?  So we make the app check GPlay regularly to check which goods are "purchased", i.e. still active and not refunded?

Comment: Yes, you check every time the app runs, generally.  The information gets cached on the device by the Google Play service and it is updated after a "while" if you process a refund or a cancelation.  These updates are not immediate.  Sometimes a reboot of the device triggers an update of this information. Subscriptions *may* trigger more reliably as the time of expiration wil be known - I have not used subscriptions yet myself.