# Android In-App Subscription PurchaseState is always 0

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-subscription

In my android app using in-app subscription monthly plan. I have purchased a subscription product with test account. After one hour I cancelled it manually from my phone.

After I query using `inventory.getPurchase(monthlyplan)`, I always get purchase state is 0.

I waited more than one day; still getting response of purchase state is 0.
 Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this document - [Subscription Cancellation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#cancellation):

> Users can view the status of all of their subscriptions and cancel them if necessary from the My Apps screen in the Play Store app. Currently, the In-app Billing API does not provide support for programatically canceling subscriptions from inside the purchasing app.
>
> When the user cancels a subscription, Google Play does not offer a refund for the current billing cycle. Instead, it allows the user to have access to the canceled subscription until the end of the current billing cycle, at which time it terminates the subscription. For example, if a user purchases a monthly subscription and cancels it on the 15th day of the cycle, Google Play will consider the subscription valid until the end of the 30th day (or other day, depending on the month).

**Important**: In all cases, you must continue to offer the content that your subscribers have purchased through their subscriptions, as long any user is able to access it. That is, you must not remove any content while any user still has an active subscription to it, even if that subscription will terminate at the end of the current billing cycle. Alternatively, you can use the [refund and revoke](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#refunds) API to revoke each subscriber's subscription (one by one) and refund their subscription payments. Removing content that any subscriber is entitled to access will result in penalties. Please see the [policies document](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=140504) for more information.

There are some good insights regarding the following (also found in the same document):

- App uninstallation
- Refunding and revoking subscriptions

Here is a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6817671/5995040) that also talk about cancelling subscription in-app.

Comment: But I am Still getting purchase state is 0 when the purchase state will be change

Comment: @user3069614 but then autoRenewing will be false, that's how you know it got cancelled. Subscription is (and should be) still valid at this point as far as Google is concerned.

Comment: This answer doesn't really solve this issue. I am also getting the same error, `purchaseState` is 0 and `autoRenewing` is true.